# Loading design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use Facebook **data load method**, when I connect to the API a blurry design list pops up and slowly pops up and out.
[check the attached image][image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use shimmer package in flutter
[shimmer](http://pub.dev/packages/shimmer)